# Can't build for iOS simulators any more after upgrading my mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I recently updated to a new Mac to develop iOS apps.  My previous system was an old MacMini2.1 version and the new one is v5.1 running an Intel Core i5 processor.

The project used to build and run fine, all I've done is installed Xcode, certificates and provisioning profiles migrated from the old mac and recompiled.

I'm sure this is a silly linker setting/path I just need to update but can't figure it out from the abstract error message.

Essentially I can build and run for the device fine but the simulators result in the following link error.

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' for architecture i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` from `Build Settings / Linking / Other Linker Flags`

Comment: Thank you!!! It was obscured on my small monitor, didn't see it hidden in there edit box.